# Throw new PXRedirectRequiredException not reloading most recent data

Tags: acumatica

In the Sales Order page, I created `PXAction` button which purpose is to save, set a user defined Checkbox field to true refresh the page.A SQL trigger runs when the checkbox is true which changes values on the SOLine Like price etc. Currently it saves and redirects to the Base object and checks a field but the new redirected page doesn't show the changes that have been completed by a SQL trigger until I manually press refresh/F5 or press my button a second time.

**But** if I do what the button does manually and just save the page, check the user defined checkbox and then **Press F5** the changes are reflected accurately(from the trigger) Is there a way I can implement a full page refresh like an **F5** instead of resorting to the `Throw new PXredirectRequiredException()`

Here's my code calling the Base object and redirecting to the Base:

```
 public PXAction<SOOrder> KSRefresh;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Recal Prices")]
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    protected virtual void kSRefresh()
    {
       SOLine sLine = PXSelect<SOLine, Where<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderNbr>>>>.Select(Base, this.Base.Document.Current.OrderNbr);
       SOOrder sOrder = PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>.Select(Base, this.Base.Document.Current.OrderNbr);
       SOOrderExt sOrderExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(sOrder);
       sOrderExt.UsrRecalcPrice = true;

   Base.Actions.PressSave();
    if (sLine != null && sLine.InventoryID.HasValue)
      {
      throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(Base, null);
      }        
    }
```

Here's my code attempting redirect to a copy instance of the base in a new instance to test if that would reflect the new changes done by the trigger:

```
   public PXAction<SOOrder> KSRefresh;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Recal Prices")]
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    protected virtual void kSRefresh()
    {
       SOLine sLine = PXSelect<SOLine, Where<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderNbr>>>>.Select(Base, this.Base.Document.Current.OrderNbr);
       SOOrder sOrder = PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>.Select(Base, this.Base.Document.Current.OrderNbr);
       SOOrderExt sOrderExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(sOrder);
       sOrderExt.UsrRecalcPrice = true;
     SOOrderEntry grp = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();

   Base.Actions.PressSave();
      grp.Document.Current = Base.Document.Current;
    if (sLine != null && sLine.InventoryID.HasValue)

     {

      throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(grp, null);
      }        
    }
```

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `grp.Document.Current = grp.Document.Search<SOLine.orderNbr>(sLine.OrderNbr);` prior to the new exception and it loaded all of the updated values correctly. Instead of just setting grp to the base document OR just throwing the exception to the Base.

Comment: Good you found something that worked for you. Make sure you include order type as it is also part of the key like so: docgraph.Document.Search<SOOrder.orderNbr>(order.OrderNbr, order.OrderType);

Answer (score 1):

When using extensions and updating a value in your dac extension you need to call an update on the base table. In your case it looks like your extension is on SOOrder so you need to call an update similar to below example:

```
//after you set your SOOrderExt.UsrRecalcPrice call this...
Base.Document.Update(sOrder);
//now call PressSave...
```

You should be able to do this without the redirect withing something like this in place of the redirect:

```
SOOrder sOrder = PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>.Select(Base, this.Base.Document.Current.OrderNbr);
SOOrderExt sOrderExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(sOrder);
sOrderExt.UsrRecalcPrice = true;
Base.Document.Update(sOrder);

Base.Actions.PressSave();

Base.Document.Current = PXSelect<SOOrder, 
                    Where<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>.Select(Base,
                        sOrder.OrderNbr);
```

Another example is the SOOrderEntry graph for the CopyOrder action. Maybe returning IEnumerable and returning a list of orders (list only contains your 1 order) to see if that refreshes. Here is the sample:

```
public PXAction<SOOrder> copyOrder;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Copy Order", MapEnableRights =     PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Visible = false)]
[PXLookupButton]
public virtual IEnumerable CopyOrder(PXAdapter adapter)
{
        List<SOOrder> list = adapter.Get<SOOrder>().ToList();
        if (copyparamfilter.AskExt(setStateFilter, true) == WebDialogResult.OK && string.IsNullOrEmpty(copyparamfilter.Current.OrderType) == false)
        {
            this.Save.Press();
            SOOrder order = PXCache<SOOrder>.CreateCopy(Document.Current);

            // Put your code here, press save, then return the list with the current document
            //this.CopyOrderProc(order, copyparamfilter.Current);

            List<SOOrder> rs = new List<SOOrder> {Document.Current};
            return rs;
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: of course i would recommend not using any sql code such as triggers and stored procedures as this goes against the benefits of using the powerful and flexible Acumatica framework.

Comment: I tried doing what you have suggested and unfortunately it did not work and ended up making the performance of the SOOrder page hang for moments while not refreshing. Additionally I understand your concern about the  using triggers and stored procedures, this will only be a temporary fix while I look for better way to implement this.

Comment: i included another example. i don't have an extension on SO Order to test. The other issue you might have is the return of the action is occurring before the trigger completes and why i thought calling another select might help. Also try PXSelectReadOnly in place of PXSelect to make sure it gets the results from the DB and not just the cache.

Comment: Hi Brendan,  I tried implementing the PXSelectReadOnly and it looks like it's not properly retrieving the orderNbr reverting the dropdown for Ordertype selection to blank while retaining the SOLine. I should mention that the behavior for PXSelect was the same as well. I'm going to try to alter the Select statement to grab the orderNbr correctly.

I also tried implementing the second solution for the IEnumerable and I wasn't able to get it to compile due to the error of it not existing within the context for setStateFilter.

Comment: I just tried the PXSelectReadOnly with an existing order(instead of a new order) and tried updating the order and pressing my button to see if it'll show the changes from the trigger unfortunately it still needed a full page refresh to reflect the changes. Thank you for all your help by the way, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you think perhaps there's a way to use Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) in the Aspx.cs to work off of a PXAction?